# Firebase dynamic links - analytics show 0 first-opens and 0 re-opens

Tags: swift, xcode, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm trying to integrate Firebase Dynamic Links into our iOS project. I've created some test links in the Firebase console and written the link handling methods in the App Delegate. Links are functioning fine, however the analytics in Firebase don't seem to be working.

So in the console, I've set up some dynamic links which exist, for example:

[image]
[image]
[image]

In `AppDelegate.swift` I've first imported FirebaseDynamicLinks:

```
import FirebaseDynamicLinks
```

Then added two methods:

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey: Any]) -> Bool {
        app.analytics?.log(eventName: "application:openURL:url 1 \(url.absoluteString)", with: options, level: .debug)

        if let dynamicLink = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().dynamicLink(fromCustomSchemeURL: url) {
            print("*** Dynamic link found through custom url scheme!")
            self.handleIncomingDynamicLink(dynamicLink)
        }

        return true
    }
```

And:

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
        if userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb {
            Adjust.appWillOpen(userActivity.webpageURL!)
        }
        let canContinue = ActivityManager.application(application, continue: userActivity)

        if let incomingURL = userActivity.webpageURL {
            let linkHandled = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(incomingURL) { dynamicLink, error in
                guard error == nil else {
                    return
                }

                if let dynamicLink = dynamicLink {
                    self.handleIncomingDynamicLink(dynamicLink)
                }
            }

            if linkHandled {
                return true
            }
            return false
        }

        return canContinue
    }
```

And finally the handling method:

```
   func handleIncomingDynamicLink(_ dynamicLink: DynamicLink) {
        guard let url = dynamicLink.url else {
            return
        }
        
        print("*** Link launched") // Not implemented yet
    }
```

Now, when I access the link, my app opens and I see `*** Link launched` in the console which is great. However, my understand was that this would then be reported as a 'First-opens' event if the app is not installed and a 'Re-opens' event if it has. However, this is not happening - I am not getting any reporting coming through. Wondering what I'm missing here.